# Erro no MongoDB/Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando iniciar meu servidor, porém ao tentar iniciar ele acusa erro no MongoDB, e eu já estou há horas procurando a solução para esse problema e até agora não achei nada.

O que complica mais ainda é o fato de que não fui eu quem criou esse servidor, e nunca utilizei o Mongoose, apenas o MongoDB em si.

Segue erro que aparece no console quando tento iniciar o servidor:

> ```
> { MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
> at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Projetos\Server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:328:35)
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
> at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Projetos\Server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
> at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
> at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
> at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Projetos\Server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:177:49)
> at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
> at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
> name: 'MongoError',
> message: 'failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect 
> [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
> (node:8348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
> (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] 
> on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
> ```

Comment: Primeiro ponto é ver qual processo está rodando na porta que o mongo deveria estar rodando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi resolvido o problema.

O que aconteceu foi o seguinte: a pessoa que tinha o DB na máquina dela deu um commit nos arquivos do servidor, e para ela estava configurado para tentar acessar o mongo no ip 127.0.0.1, e acabou configurando o mesmo ip na minha máquina, dando erro no acesso ao mongo.

Erro infantil da minha parte...